# How do you make text in a div sit at the bottom of the div?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to place text over a background image for a header element (id="blogheader") on my page but I can't seem to get the text to sit at the bottom of the div. I have tried a couple things including 'vertical-align: bottom' and vertical-align: text-bottom'.

I figure there is something I'm just missing or an easier way to get the result I want but I'm still learning how to code properly! :)

Here's the HTML:

```
<main id="blogpage">
            <h2 id="blogheader">The Blog!</h2>

            <div id="popblogs">Most Popular Blogs</div>
            <div id="recentblogs">Most Recent Blogs</div>

            <section>
                <article id="art1">
                    <h3>Topic One</h3>
                </article>
            </section>
</main>
```

And the CSS:

```
#blogheader         {clear: both;
                    text-align: center;
                    background-image: url(Photos/image.jpg);
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    font-size: 5em;
                    color: #00c3d5;
                    height: 400px;
                    vertical-align: text-bottom;}
```

Also, any code criticism would be greatly appreciated since I am in a course currently learning all this stuff and it doesn't hurt to have some expert advice!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/ that's not what vertical align does, could you create a fiddle

Comment: have you looked at [`position:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)? I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use display:table-cell or flex:

- flex

```css
#blogheader {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(Photos/image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #00c3d5;
  /* send content down */
  height: 400px;display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<main id="blogpage">
  <h2 id="blogheader">The Blog!</h2>

  <div id="popblogs">Most Popular Blogs</div>
  <div id="recentblogs">Most Recent Blogs</div>

  <section>
    <article id="art1">
      <h3>Topic One</h3>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

- table-cell

```css
#blogheader {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(Photos/image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #00c3d5;
  height: 400px;
  /* send content down */
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<main id="blogpage">
  <h2 id="blogheader">The Blog!</h2>

  <div id="popblogs">Most Popular Blogs</div>
  <div id="recentblogs">Most Recent Blogs</div>

  <section>
    <article id="art1">
      <h3>Topic One</h3>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

To put the text at the bottom of the element, you can assign `display: flex;` to `#blogheader` and then `justify-content: center;` to center the child text horizontally, and `align-items: flex-end;` to push the child text to the flex-end/bottom.

```css
#blogheader {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(Photos/image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #00c3d5;
  height: 400px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<main id="blogpage">
            <h2 id="blogheader">The Blog!</h2>

            <div id="popblogs">Most Popular Blogs</div>
            <div id="recentblogs">Most Recent Blogs</div>

            <section>
                <article id="art1">
                    <h3>Topic One</h3>
                </article>
            </section>
</main>
```